# Помогите с пунктуацией 4

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания? Если нет, то почему?

*Но, к сожалению, как бы ни старался, результаты очень расстраивают меня: запоминаю очень мало и неточно, не улавливаю сути; возникают сложности при изложении этой информации (не могу сформулировать, воспроизвести в правильной последовательности, даже описать в общих чертах).*

Answer (score 1):

Но, к сожалению, как бы ни старался, результаты очень расстраивают меня: запоминаю очень мало и неточно, не улавливаю сути; **также** возникают сложности при изложении этой информации (не могу сформулировать, воспроизвести в правильной последовательности, даже описать в общих чертах).

**Пояснение**

Основой текста является его **содержание**, для которой автор подбирает походящую структурно-грамматическую форму. **Менее всего следует править авторское содержание**, а оно здесь достаточно ясное: возникают трудности (1) при восприятии информации и (2) при изложении ее.

**Форма текста вполне выражает его смысл, он читается и понимается легко.** Две проблемы обозначены; грамматические формы разнообразны, но при этом вполне  сочетаются друг с другом, позволяя в рамках  одного предложения передать всю нужную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно вроде, не считая того, что в конце не было точки.

Answer (score 0):

Надо полагать, что об упомянутой некой информации речь шла в предыдущей фразе, и  слова *при изложении этой информации* оказались слишком оторваны и задвинуты в конец перечисления, что усугубляется ещё и чтк/зпт (не вижу нужды здесь в этом знаке). Поэтому следовало бы приблизить их к первой части предложения перестановкой (1), или связать фразу воедино хотя бы посредством тире (2).

*Но, к сожалению, как бы ни старался, результаты очень расстраивают меня: запоминаю очень мало и неточно, не улавливаю сути этой информации, возникают сложности при её изложении* ().

*Но, к сожалению, как бы ни старался, результаты очень расстраивают меня: запоминаю очень мало и неточно, не улавливаю сути — возникают сложности при изложении этой информации* ().